# Using a char as a vector index

Tags: c++

Say, I have a string and a vector of `bool`s. Based on the characters in the string, I want to set the corresponding vector indices to true.

```
std::vector<bool> is_present(256, false);
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
{
    is_present[str[i]] = true;
}
```

From what I understand, the standard does not define the signed-ness of a char. Depending on the platform, it may be signed or unsigned. On most platforms, signed char will be an 8-bit two's complement number (-128 to 127), and unsigned char will be an 8-bit unsigned integer (0 to 255).

If that is the case, is there a possibility that `str[i]` will return a negative number and cause a memory fault in `is_present[str[i]]`? or is the `char` getting typecast to `vector<bool>::size_type` which is `unsigned` and hence no problems can occur?

Also, is it better to use `vector<bool> is_present(pow(2, CHAR_BIT)), false)` instead of hardcoding it to 256?

Comment: It might not return a negative number, but a *very big* number instead, which would be equally bad

Comment: If you are reading ASCII characters, they should always be positive since the defined range is 0..127.  Expanded character sets may have the range 0..255, in which you will have to read as an unsigned char.

Comment: Yes - there could be a problem. You should ensure `[i]` is non-negative and properly in range. Best way to express it is probably `static_cast<unsigned char>(i)`, but there are myriad others e.g. `(unsigned char)i`, `reintrepret_cast<unsigned char&>(i)`, `i >= 0 ? i : 256 + i` (same caveats for 256 you note). Re `CHAR_BIT`, I'd say it's a bit over-kill, but at least it's clear what the significance of the dimension is. Up to you.  You might also consider a `bitset` - search the site to read about the issues with `vector<bool>`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always cast a `char` to an `unsigned char` if you want to be definite about the values.

You can say `1u << CHAR_BIT` to get the desired size.

```
std::vector<bool> is_present(1u << CHAR_BIT, false);
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
{
    is_present[static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i])] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do it like this I would use `std::numeric_limits<std::string::char_type>::min()` and then subtract that from the value to ensure it always starts at 0, what ever the range of the char type:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int main() {
  const std::string str = "hello world";
  std::vector<bool> is_present(256, false);
  for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
    is_present[static_cast<int>(str[i]) - std::numeric_limits<std::string::value_type>::min()] = true;
  }
}
```

You'd want to use `max()` and `min()` for the initial size of the vector too though.

Comment: Who would want to do **that**?!? There is pretty little ambiguity of the value type of `std::string` given that it is defined to be `std::basic_string<char>`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl - there's always the possibility that it's actually a template argument in the "real" code where this is going to be used and thus not fixed as `std::string`, or even some alternative string type. More importantly there's no harm in always referring to things like sizes and value_types via an appropriate `typedef` - it can never hurt, but it can save pain

Comment: if so, you'd also need to make sure that the array is big enough, e.g. `is_present(std::numeric_limits<decltype(str[i])>::max() - int(std::numeric_limits<decltype(str[i])>::min())`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl - which is exactly what the final sentence of my answer says :)

Answer (score 2):

Type promotion between integers first expands the value to the appropriate size and then possibly changes the type. It is one of the favorite errors with the `<cctype>` functions for people to "forget" that these can only be used with positive values and that `char` may lead negative values. For example, in a locale supporting ISO-Latin-1 (ISO/IEC 8859-1:1998) trying to uppercase my name will have catastrophic results on platforms where `char` is signed.

The proper way to deal with this to use e.g. `static_cast<unsigned char>(c)` or, assuming you have included `<cinttypes>`, something like `std::uint8_t(c)`. To determine the appropriate size of an array of `char` you would, of course, use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()`: using `pow()` is a bit of an overkill for this. In general, you would rather use the shift operators (on an `unsigned` type) than `pow()` when you need powers of 2.

Answer (score 2):

> If that is the case, is there a possibility that str[i] will return a negative number

Yes it will

> and cause a memory fault in is_present[str[i]]?

Yes, you will get undefined behaviour from this code.

> or is the char getting typecast to `vector<bool>::size_type` which is unsigned

Yes, it will get converted to an unsigned type.

> and hence no problems can occur?

No, this will wrap and give you a "very large" number instead, and it is the access to this value outside your array bounds that will cause the problem

So instead you need to explicitly cast to an `unsigned char` first.

```
is_present[static_cast<unsigned char>(str[i])] = true
```

Which I believe is guaranteed to wrap in the right way.

> Also, is it better to use vector is_present(pow(2, CHAR_BIT)), false) instead of hardcoding it to 256?

Personally I'd not worry too much about systems where chars are not 8 bits, I'd suspect that a lot of other things might break first. If I was being really worried about it I'd probably just do this

```
#if CHAR_BIT!=8
   #error "This code will not work for non-8bit-char systems"
#endif
```

Comment: To the last point: `vector<bool> is_present(UCHAR_MAX+1, false);` would handle weird implementations without being particularly contorted or confusing code (although it doesn't handle the extra-weird case of `UCHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX`). If all else fails, sure, check that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, but often it's pretty easy to remain agnostic about it.

Answer (score 0):

`static_cast<unsigned char>(c)`  is OK. 
Converting char to unsigned char  acts like filling bits of unsigned char with bits of source char.

I prefer `CHAR_MAX` or `UCHAR_MAX` to pow,simple and distinct.

My question is why the char in string could be negative,while it would be used as subscript?I mean,if it is an subscript of vector or some vector-like container,it must be positive.I think what you really want is assert.

Code like this:

```
std::vector<bool> is_present(CHAR_MAX, false);
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
{
    assert( str[i]>=0 && str[i]<=127 );
    is_present[str[i]] = true;
}
```